# previous radius and next radius

Tags: pseudocode, angle

For my explanation I will use degrees.

Let's say I have an angle of 45 degrees seen from the center of a canvas.
I have objects at 10°, 60°, 180° and 350° seen from the center.

In this case the previous angle from 45° is 10°.
The next angle from 45° is 60°.

**But now the problem:**

What if the angle is 6°, for example. Then the previous angle is 350°.
Or if the angle is 355°, then the next angle is 10°.

How can I figure out which one to get, assuming we have an array similar to the following?

```
angles = [10, 60, 180, 350]
theAngle = 45
```

Psuedo-code will do.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If the angle is smaller than the first element in the array then, assuming the array is sorted and within the range 0..359, the previous angle will be the last element in the array.  I thought this would be obvious once you wrote it down on paper.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a modulo operator, e.g. to find the "previous" angle using C or C-like languages:

```
int N = 4;
int angles[N] = { 10, 60, 180, 350 };
int theAngle = 45;

int prevAngle = angles[0];          // init - assume angle[0] is "previous" angle
int minAngleDelta = (theAngle - prevAngle) % 360;
for (i = 1; i < N; ++i)             // for each remaining angle
{
    int angleDelta = (theAngle - angles[i]) % 360;
    if (angleDelta < minAngleDelta) // if we found a smaller delta (modulo 360)
    {                      
        minAngleDelta = angleDelta; // track min angle delta
        prevAngle = angles[i];      // and corresponding angle
    }                    
}
```

Note: this works even if your array of angles is not sorted.